# Jsfiddle not functioning properly when viewed on IOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, jsfiddle

This is an issue I've been experiencing only for the last few days; when following a link to jsfiddle, or even going to the jsfiddle homepage (on IOS 6, iPad 2), jsfiddle doesn't initialise properly, and all I see is "initialising the awesome". Even logging in and creating a fiddle doesn't work. The issue only seems to have appeared since some recent downtime which I assume they were updating jsfiddle during it. Has anyone else experienced this issue/have a fix?

NB: this occurs on both safari and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've sent an email to jsfiddle support, and I came up with this response:

> We're working on that.
>   https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/330
>
> For the moment please use draft feature or add /embedded/result to the
>   URL.
>
> http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#draft-page
>
> Regards, Piotr

Hopefully this means that the issue will be fixed soon, however, in the meantime, use: (for example)
http://jsfiddle.net/ (your fiddle)/embedded/result

I.e, just add /embedded/result to the end of the url as Piotr suggested.